# Button does not do anything, Android

Tags: java, android

I've tried to make app that will call a given number. But I cant resolve the problem why my call button wont work. When I push it, nothing happens.
Here is mine main activity file:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                final Intent intent = callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("868686899"));

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is android manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

How can I resolve this problem? Thank you for your help. Also here is how the app looks like:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOQ2e.png)

activity-main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="call" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check your log messages and include it here

Comment: On what android version you are running your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Intent* this way:

```
String phone = "868686899";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
startActivity(intent);
```

Or if you want to be more security-conscious:

```
String phone = "868686899";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
startActivity(intent);
```

The `ACTION_DIAL` do not require `CALL_PHONE` permission

Comment: No, you do not need a rooted device, if you attach a log somewhere i try to help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
```

I think problem is here, if permission is not granted, app do nothing. Should ask request permission dialog for android 6 and above:

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] 
 {android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},PHONE_CALL_REQUEST_CODE);
```